# How to assign smaller array to larger in overlapping area

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to put a small 8x7 2D array, inside an 8x8 2D array.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
--> Array called 'a' with shape 8x7

a = [[ 16.,  11.,  10.,  16.,  24.,  40.,  51.],
     [ 12.,  12.,  14.,  19.,  26.,  58.,  60.],
     [ 14.,  13.,  16.,  24.,  40.,  57.,  69.],
     [ 14.,  17.,  22.,  29.,  51.,  87.,  80.],
     [ 18.,  22.,  37.,  56.,  68., 109., 103.],
     [ 24.,  35.,  55.,  64.,  81., 104., 113.],
     [ 49.,  64.,  78.,  87., 103., 121., 120.],
     [ 72.,  92.,  95.,  98., 112., 100., 103.]]


--> Array called 'b' with shape 8x8

b = [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]
```

So basically, what I want is:

```
--> Array called 'c' with shape 8x8

c = [[ 16.,  11.,  10.,  16.,  24.,  40.,  51., 0],
     [ 12.,  12.,  14.,  19.,  26.,  58.,  60., 0],
     [ 14.,  13.,  16.,  24.,  40.,  57.,  69., 0],
     [ 14.,  17.,  22.,  29.,  51.,  87.,  80., 0],
     [ 18.,  22.,  37.,  56.,  68., 109., 103., 0],
     [ 24.,  35.,  55.,  64.,  81., 104., 113., 0],
     [ 49.,  64.,  78.,  87., 103., 121., 120., 0],
     [ 72.,  92.,  95.,  98., 112., 100., 103., 0]]
```

Is there an easy way to do this, preferably without using loops, like 'for' , 'while', 'map' 
or list comprehension?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just slice assign to `b` up to the dimensions of `a`:

```
x, y = a.shape
b[:x, :y] = a
```

---

```
print(b)
array([[ 16.,  11.,  10.,  16.,  24.,  40.,  51.,   0.],
       [ 12.,  12.,  14.,  19.,  26.,  58.,  60.,   0.],
       [ 14.,  13.,  16.,  24.,  40.,  57.,  69.,   0.],
       [ 14.,  17.,  22.,  29.,  51.,  87.,  80.,   0.],
       [ 18.,  22.,  37.,  56.,  68., 109., 103.,   0.],
       [ 24.,  35.,  55.,  64.,  81., 104., 113.,   0.],
       [ 49.,  64.,  78.,  87., 103., 121., 120.,   0.],
       [ 72.,  92.,  95.,  98., 112., 100., 103.,   0.]])
```